# Returning Task<int> freezes the UI?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have this generic method:

```
public static async Task<int> SaveChangesWithAuditingAsync<TLogType>(ObjectContext dbContext, DbSet<TLogType> logsSet, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DbChangeTracker changeTracker)
            where TLogType : class, new()
        {
            ObjectContext context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;

            await context.SaveChangesAsync(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);


            var audits = new List<TLogType>();

            foreach (var entry in changeTracker.Entries().Where(o => o.State == EntityState.Modified || o.State == EntityState.Added).ToList())
            {
                var changeType = entry.State.ToString();
                Type entityType = GetEntityType(entry);

                string tableName = GetTableName(context, entityType);

                var audit = new TbCommonHistoryLog
                {
                    ObjectJson = GetEntityAsJson(entry),
                    TableName = tableName,
                };
                TLogType t = new TLogType();
                t.ChargeFrom(audit);
                audits.Add(t);
            }

            logsSet.AddRange(audits);
            int result = 0;
            try
            {
                result = await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var m = ex.Message;
                return result;
            }

        }
```

I created it because I have more than one `DbContext`, and I need to have this same code, so I created `AuditHelper` class to hold this method. All `DbContext`s have the same table structure (but with different names) that is  `TLogType`. `ChargeFrom` just copies th values from one object to another.

The problem is when I call it from the overridden SaveChanges() method, the UI freezes:

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            return SaveChangesWithAuditingAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result;
        }
```

I noticed that calling it inside `SaveChanges`, there is no problem.

the `async` version of `SaveChanges`:

```
   public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            return SaveChangesWithAuditingAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        }

        public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return SaveChangesWithAuditingAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```

EDIT:

this is `SaveChangesWithAuditingAsync`

```
  private async Task<int> SaveChangesWithAuditingAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
     return await AuditHelper.SaveChangesWithAuditingAsync(((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext, TbHistoryLog, cancellationToken, ChangeTracker);
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain to us what `.Result` does? If you can, then you know your problem. If you cannot, then why do you use it? Unfortunately it is a common made mistake.

Comment: As far I know that is how I extract the result from a task which is just `int`

Comment: Yes, but it does it in a blocking fashion. So you made all these async calls and it the end you just say: hey, block here until you can giver me the result. `public override int SaveChanges()` should ideally be   `public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()` and await the call to `SaveChangesWithAuditingAsync`. And of course this awaiting should be done all the way up unto the call from the UI

Comment: The code was working OK when it was inside the `DbContext` class without generics

Comment: I understand, but the project I'm working on has numerous `SaveChanges` calls, that will take a lot of time changing it

Comment: I fail to see what relation there is between blocking calls and the use of generics. But that could be me :-) Could you post that code that did work?

Comment: Then you have to stick with the blocking situation. There just is no real alternative. It async/await to the top or nothing. Please read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx, especially the section "Async All the Way"

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling the `async` version

Comment: @Fabulous added the code

Comment: I added `SaveChangesWithAuditingAsync` method, I forgot to add it!

Comment: Just don't block on your code, `await` also extracts the result from task, but not in a blocking way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I call it from the overridden SaveChanges() method, the UI freezes

Yes, [the call to `Result` is causing a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Ideally, the best way to avoid this is to not call `SaveChanges` at all - just use `SaveChangesAsync` instead, and throw an exception from `SaveChanges` saying that synchronous APIs are not supported.

If this is unacceptable, then you can look into using [one of the hacks in my article on brownfield asynchronous code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx). Note that each hack has its own drawbacks, and ***there is no hack that works in every scenario***.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, when I call `SaveChangesAsync()` this problem was happening: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45413944/overriding-savechangesasync-when-enclosed-inside-transactionscope , as my comment states, I managed to solve it. by a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use .Result, it waits for the result to be available on the calling thread blocking further execution.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're not awaiting your call to `SaveChangesWithAuditingAsync` in `SaveChanges()` - that won't do you any favours. It might be a pain to add all over the place, but it's needed if you don't want to have crashes or hangs.