# Overriding SaveChangesAsync when enclosed inside TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactionscope

I'm fairly new to EF transactions, this is the code that is used for saving

```
public bool Save(TbArea area, bool isNew, out string errMsg)
        {
            try
            {
                errMsg = string.Empty;
    using (var oScope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            TbArea oEntity = oContext.TbArea.Where(a => a.AreaCode == area.AreaCode && a.CompanyId == MainClass.SystemCompanyId).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (oEntity != null)
                            {
                                if (isNew) { errMsg = Resources.ResSales.MsgRecordCodeDublicated; return false; }
                                oContext.TbArea.Attach(oEntity);
                                oContext.Entry(oEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(area);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (!isNew) { errMsg = Resources.ResSales.MsgRecordNotFoundInDB; return false; }
                                oContext.TbArea.Add(area);
                            }

                            oContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                            oScope.Complete();
                            return true;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            oScope.Dispose();
                            errMsg = ex.Message;
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
```

I'm overriding `SaveChangesAsync`
so that I can save the `ChangeTracker.Entries` into the database.
this is a portion of the code:

```
    dbContext.AcceptAllChanges();
    logsSet.AddRange(audits);
    int result = 0;
    try
      {
         result = await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                //scope.Complete(); there was a transaction that I commented out, I thought it might overlaps the original transaction!

          return result;
       }
     catch (Exception ex)
          {
             var m = ex.Message;
             return result;
          }
```

When I save an item, I get the error :

> the transaction has aborted

when I remove the transaction scope the saving happens normally!

Comment: Why do you have mentioned time stamp?? Is this a log running operation??

Comment: No, I removed it and still getting the same error

Comment: I moved the TransactionScope to the overridden method and it works now

Comment: Although perhaps omitted in your MVCE, note that SaveAllChanges is done under a (single phase) transaction. TransactionScope would only be needed if other activities were needed. Also, the explicit oscope.Dispose in the exception handler isn't needed - its already covered in the wrapping using block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is marking the transaction complete before the changes have finished saving:

```
oContext.SaveChangesAsync();
oScope.Complete();
```

You need to use `await`:

```
await oContext.SaveChangesAsync();
oScope.Complete();
```

If you're in a context where `await` can resume on a different thread, you'll probably also need to specify `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled`.

Comment: The problem is that this method taket `out string` as parameter so I can't mark it `async`!

Comment: Then change your return type to include all `out` parameters.